# Sum of weighted chi square distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1 \sim \chi_{k}^2$ and $X_2 \sim \chi_{k}^2$ be i.i.d and both $a_1$ and $a_2$ positive real values.

How can be expressed the PDF of $Y = a_1X_1 + a_2X_2$? Is it also a chi-square distribution?

thanks

Comment: According to this article, it would appear that it's a scaled infinite sum of gamma distributions: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812218490066X

Comment: Thr are several misunderstandings in your question. You write "both i.i.d" which doesnt have maning, you probably want only "i.i.d."  To be iid is not a property one random variable can have, it is a property of a collection of random variables (here $X, Y$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A linear combination of chi-squared random variables is not, in general, chi-squared**

The answer is NO unless the $a_i$ are either 0 or 1. This is easy to see by looking at moment generating functions. (Also, by looking
at means and variances, see Addendum.)

**Such distributions occur often in practice.**

The issue of the distribution $Y$ is of interest in many
practical situations. An elementary example is in trying to 
find a confidence interval (CI) for the 'batch' variance $\sigma_B$ in a
random-effects one-factor ANOVA model $Y_{ij} = \mu + B_{i} + e_{ij},$
where $i = 1,\dots,b$ batches, $j = 1, \dots, r$ replications
per batch, $B_i \text{ iid Norm(}0, \sigma_B^2\text{)}$ and
$e_{ij} \text{i id Norm (}0, \sigma_e^2\text{)}.$

The error mean
square in the ANOVA table is an unbiased estimate of $\sigma_e^2$ and a CI for it can be
constructed using an obvious chi-squared distribution. However,
the mean square for batches is influenced by both $\sigma_A^2$
and $\sigma_e^2.$ 
A method of moments estimate of $\sigma_A^2$
is a linear combination of the two mean squared terms and its distribution
would be a linear combination of chi-squared distributions.

You might look at some of the methods that have
been attempted to approximate the distribution and find CIs for
batch variances. In this case, one of the $a_i$s is negative. (One very nice solution to the problem involves a
Bayesian formulation of the ANOVA and using a Gibbs sampler
to get an interval estimate, but that has nothing to do with
solving your problem.)

***Addendum with simulation:*** Below is a brief simulation of 100,000 realizations of $S = X_1 + X_2,$
where $X_1 \sim \text{Chisq}(5), X_2 \sim \text{Chisq}(10)$ and
also of $T = 3X_1 + 0.5X_2.$ The sample of $S$ passes a Kolmogrorv-
Smirnov goodness-of-fit test for matching $\text{Chisq}(15)$ and
also has mean and variance compatible with this distribution.
However, there can be no chi-squared distribution with mean
$E(T) = 3(5) + 0.5(10) = 20$ and variance $V(T) = 9(10) + 0.25(20) = 95 \ne 40.$

In practical applications, distributions of linear combinations
of chi-squared random variables are often approximated by simulation.

```
 x1 = rchisq(10^5, 5);  x2 = rchisq(10^5, 10)
 s = x1 + x2;  mean(s);  var(s)
 ## 15.02936  # E(S) = 15 as for Chisq(15)
 ## 30.07302  # V(S) = 30 as for Chisq(15)
 t = 3*x1 + .5*x2;  mean(t);  var(t)
 ## 20.00794  # Not a possible combination of
 ## 94.5343   #   mean and var for a chisq distn.
```

Answer (score 8):

PDF of weighted sum of TWO iid chi-square distributions:

Please check page 5 Corollary 1
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.2691.pdf

[image: Weighted sum of TWO iid chi-square distributions]